# How to avoid downloading duplicates (pdfs) while scraping websites many times per day?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm using Selenium ChromeDriver in Python to automate checking for new pdf docs posted to a site, downloading those new docs, then extracting the data and placing it into Excel. I'm running the script 4 times per day on the same site. There may be docs posted in the morning, afternoon, and late afternoon.

How do I *not* download and extract the same pdfs in the afternoon that I already had that morning?

I've looked into chrome extensions that prevent duplicate downloads, but when Selenium opens a new window in Chrome, it's not logged in to the browser, therefore extensions on my main profile are not present.

Comment: How about checking the filenames? What code have you tried?

Comment: Log the file names/paths/URIs that you've already downloaded.